# Incorrect cross-reference syntax gives confusing "undefined label" warning

Tags: python-sphinx

Revising the title since I figured out that the problem was totally different than what I thought it was. Should I delete this question or leave it out here in case someone else makes this same mistake?

Original title was: Some Sphinx cross-references don't recognize section title?

Original question:

I'm seeing some really odd behavior - I have cross-references in my Sphinx markup according to http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#ref-role

but when I build the document (HTML or LaTEXPDF) I get these errors on some of them:

> WARNING: undefined label: _unhiding (if the link has no caption the label must precede a section header)

Thing is, the working and nonworking ones look exactly the same to me.

Working:

```
.. _conditions:

Monitoring Conditions and Alerts
================================
```

Broken:

```
.. _performance:  

Viewing System Performance
==========================
```

Also broken:

```
.. _unhiding:  

Unhiding Conditions and Canceling Auto-Dismiss
-----------------------------------------------
```

I even copied the working one and replaced the reference term, but that didn't help.

I should be able to work around this by explicitly defining the captions, but this is mystifying....

Comment: In case it matters, I have not yet updated to 1.3.3.

Answer (score 8):

AUGH! Never mind, the title warning was a red herring.

The problem was in the references - I was including the _ in the reference text, but it's secretly not part of the key. I forgot this since I used references a few weeks ago and it's not obvious from the documentation.

Doesn't work:

```
:ref:`_unhiding`
```

Does work:

```
:ref:`unhiding`
```